# How to show the current status of the downloading file in the popup of the chrome extension?

Tags: ajax, flask, google-chrome-extension

There is a python server that receives a GET request with a `file_id` and it triggers downloading that file from another website to a local directory at the python server side. This is done by ajax request in `popup.js`. I can get the percentage of the downloading file and I can log it continuously in the console. Problem is that I want to show that status as a downloading bar in the `popup.html`. Is there a way to continuously listen on a event after request like `socket.io`? I really stuck thinking about how to implement that.

**python server**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<file_id>", methods = ['GET'])
def main(course_id):
    // trigger the file downloader this is running asynchronously and 
    // logs the amount of downloading  

    response = jsonify({'message': file_id + ' will be downloaded!!'})
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#download_button').click(function(){
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['fileID'], function(result) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:80/"+result.fileID,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response) {
              alert("success: "+response.message);
            // here I need to start showing the status of the downloading file
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error");
            }
         });
        })
    });
});
```

Please help me to design this use case, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seems easy: you can periodically make a request to your server using setInterval. Or maybe you can use push-notifications, look for tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own problem. I got this resolved by generating `url`s for the files and send them as the respond to the `jQuery` request. Then downloading status of each file could be handled independently without much of struggle.